# How can I mock data for this.getResults$.subscribe in angular for unit test cases?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, ngrx-store

```
displayMesssage(){
this.getResults$.subscribe(data =>{
if(data !== undefined && data !== null){
 this.message = data.message;
}else{
 this.message="Empty";
});
}
```

How can I mock data for the above use case in jasmine?

Comment: Can you show us how `getResults$` is defined/implemented?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this, it may work. If this doesn't work, I need to see the full spec and full component.

```
import { of } from 'rxjs';
....
it('should set message to data.message when not null or undefined', () => {
  component.getResults$ = of({ message: 'hello world' });
  component.displayMessage();
  expect(component.message).toBe('hello world');
});

it('should set message to "Empty" if getResults$ is falsy', () => {
  component.getResults$ = of(null);
  component.displayMessage();
  expect(component.message).toBe('Empty');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    const data = { res: "put your data here" };
    resolve(data);
  }, 2000);
});
```

[Stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-crud-example-with-mock-services?file=src%2Fapp%2Fservices%2Fget-all-customers.service.ts) with mock services